# Can't call `ioutil.ReadDir` on `/dev/fd` on MacOS

Tags: macos, go

I tried to run the following Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    items, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/dev/fd")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(items)
}
```

I just get this error:

```
panic: lstat /dev/fd/4: bad file descriptor

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/andy/Desktop/demo.go:11 +0xe8
exit status 2
```

The `/dev/fd` folder definitely exists, and there is a `/dev/fd/4` inside there when I `ls` it.

```
$ ls -Al /dev/fd
total 9
crw--w----  1 andy  tty     16,   4 Jan 25 00:16 0
crw--w----  1 andy  tty     16,   4 Jan 25 00:16 1
crw--w----  1 andy  tty     16,   4 Jan 25 00:16 2
dr--r--r--  3 root  wheel      4419 Jan 23 20:42 3/
dr--r--r--  1 root  wheel         0 Jan 23 20:42 4/
```

What's going on? Why can't I read this directory? I'm trying to port the `ls` command to Go [here](https://github.com/acarl005/ls-go), so I would like to be able to read this directory in order to produce similar output to `ls`.

**EDIT:** I am running everything as non-root user. The executable bit on `/dev/fd` *is* set.

```
$ ls -al /dev | grep fd
dr-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel                 0 Jan 23 20:42 fd/

$ stat /dev/fd/4 # same result with -L flag
stat: /dev/fd/4: stat: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: What is the output of command `stat /dev/fd/4` or `stat -L /dev/fd/4` ?

Comment: `/dev/fd` is rarely interacted with directly, and OSX seems to have  [some issues](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1652807) with it when treated as a regular filesystem. Still, if you want to see exactly what it's doing, try `strace ls -li /dev/fd`. In general, it's recommended to exclude `/dev/fd` (or even `/dev`) from regular file processing.

Comment: `stat /dev/fd/4` produces same error: `stat: Bad file descriptor`. I don't seem to have an `strace` command on my machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's remember that /dev/fd is special. Its contents are different for every process (since they reflect the file descriptors of that process), so it doesn't really mean anything that `ls` can list it because its contents will be different for `ls` and your program.

Anyway, here's a slightly updated version of your program where instead of letting ioutil do things behind our back, we do it ourselves to see what's going on:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "os"
        "log"
)

func main() {
        d, err := os.Open("/dev/fd")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        names, err := d.Readdirnames(0)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for _, n := range names {
                n = "/dev/fd/" + n
                fmt.Printf("file: %s\n", n)
                _, err := os.Lstat(n)
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Printf("lstat error: %s - %v\n", n, err)
                }
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 200)
}
```

And then when run it gives me:

```
file: /dev/fd/0
file: /dev/fd/1
file: /dev/fd/2
file: /dev/fd/3
file: /dev/fd/4
lstat error: /dev/fd/4 - lstat /dev/fd/4: bad file descriptor
```

So this is indeed the same problem. I added the sleep at the end so that the process doesn't die so that we can debug which file descriptors it has. In another terminal:

```
$ lsof -p 7861
COMMAND  PID USER   FD     TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
foo     7861  art  cwd      DIR        1,4     2272     731702 /Users/art/src/go/src
foo     7861  art  txt      REG        1,4  1450576 8591078117 /private/var/folders/m7/d614cd9x61s0l3thb7cf3rkh0000gn/T/go-build268777304/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/foo
foo     7861  art  txt      REG        1,4   837248 8590944844 /usr/lib/dyld
foo     7861  art    0u     CHR       16,4   0t8129        645 /dev/ttys004
foo     7861  art    1u     CHR       16,4   0t8129        645 /dev/ttys004
foo     7861  art    2u     CHR       16,4   0t8129        645 /dev/ttys004
foo     7861  art    3r     DIR 37,7153808        0        316 /dev/fd
foo     7861  art    4u  KQUEUE                                count=0, state=0x8
```

We can see that fd 4 is a KQUEUE. Kqueue file descriptors are used for managing events on OSX, similar to `epoll` on Linux if you know that mechanism.

It appears that OSX does not allow `stat` on kqueue file descriptors in `/dev/fd` which we can verify with:

```
$ cat > foo.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd = kqueue();
    char path[16];
    struct stat st;

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/dev/fd/%d", fd);
    if (lstat(path, &st) == -1)
        err(1, "lstat");
    return 0;
}
$ cc -o foo foo.c && ./foo
foo: lstat: Bad file descriptor
$
```

Go programs on OSX need a kqueue to handle various events (not exactly sure which, but probably signals, timers and various file events).

You have four options here: don't stat, ignore the error, don't touch /dev/fd because it's weird, convince Apple that this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running your code as a non-`root` user, I'd *guess* that the problem is that the directory doesn't have the *execute* bit set, which prevents `chdir`-ing to that directory (which `ReadDir` might do before attempting to read the contents).

Comment: Yep I'm running everything as non-root. The execute bit *is* set, though. See edit.

Comment: @AndyCarlson To be clear, I was talking about the execute bit on `/dev/fd/4` - since that's what the error is referencing - not on its parent.

Comment: My understanding is the the execute bit is required for *opening* a directory. But I can't even `stat` the directory. I should still be able to `stat` a dir without the `-x` bit.